# Multiple data-types HTML/jQuery for filterable portfolio

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to customize the [filterable portfolio](http://mazeofminds.com/533/filterable-portfolio-powered-by-jquery/) plugin by Asta.

What the plugin does, is only show images from the selected category. It links particular images to a category using a 'data-type' like so:

```
<li data-id="id-1" data-type="blackandwhite">
```

My question is; Is it possible to give one list item multiple data-types? If so, how?

I tried searching for this problem, but oddly enough couldn't find an answer to this seemingly simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. This plugin uses `li[data-type~=+$filterClass+]` selector named "Attribute Contains Word". It means that you can add multiple types, delimited by spaces:
e.g. `<li data-id="id-1" data-type="blackandwhite red someothercategory">`

Comment: Can't believe I didn't just blindly try that. But it works! Thanks for the explanation aswell.